# Filters within ReportViewer control (used reporting services with AS Cubes)

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I have created a report with SQL reporting services and used Analysis services Cubes as a datasource. I also defined some filters at the time of report design.
When I use reportserver to view report, all works fine, report displays based on the filters selected also.
Now I used ReportViewer control to view the report on my application. I set ReportServerUrl, ReportPath and used ReportServerCredentials for authorization. 
When I executed my aspx screen it displayed me report correctly but the filter was not working. Every time I changed filter values and clicked on ViewReport button, it automatically resets the filter values.

Any ideas?? Thoughts? or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I found issue with my code. I was assigning credentials on every post back, I just added credentials inside !IsPostBack condition and it worked.